# Delete performance vs select on multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, inner-join, sql-delete

I'm trying to perform a massive delete.

I thought that using joins instead of subqueries made it more performant.

I came up with this query:

```
delete t1
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2  on t1.a = t2.a
    join table3 t3  on t2.b = t3.b;
```

it takes an awful long time, even when no row is deleted, although the select equivalent is instanteanous:

```
select *
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a
    join table3 t3 on t2.b = t3.b;
```

Why is that ? How could I make my first query faster ?

Edit: the execution plan

```
mysql> explain delete t1 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a join table3 t3 on t2.b = t3.b;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref      | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | NULL       | index | PRIMARY                  | b        | 257     | NULL     |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | DELETE      | t1    | NULL       | ref   | a,FK2354764DB4B32        | a        | 8       | db.t2.a  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                     | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     | 5000 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+----------+------+----------+-------------+
```

edit2: another try with select exists

```
mysql> explain delete from table1 t1 where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a and exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.b = t2.b));
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows | filtered | Extra                                                             |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | DELETE             | t1    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 10000|   100.00 | Using where                                                       |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | db.t1.a       |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t3    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 5000 |    10.00 | Using where; FirstMatch(t2); Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks

Comment: In general single-table DELETE which uses WHERE EXISTS is more (but slightly) fast. In shown variant server performs SELECT for to gather the rows which it must delete then performs the deletion as a transaction (writing new data and undo log makes this process slow).

Comment: You can take a look at the execution plan and see if there's anything that jumps out. It'll give you more specific information as to what your actual bottleneck is compared to anything generic that can be said here. Since we don't actually know your table structures, keys, indexes etc. If you want to share the execution plan, you can post it through [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: How large is the table?  How many rows are being deleted?  How many rows does the `select` return?

Comment: t2 has 10.000 rows and t3 has 5000 rows. t3 is a temp table with a single column that contains all the keys that will be deleted from t2 (b keys). But before deleting from t2, I need to delete all fk that point to t2 (a keys), so that's why I need to delete from t1.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: What version?  There were changes recently in `DELETE ... JOIN` optimization.

Comment: More tips on big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to delete a significant number of rows in the table, it is often faster to move the rows you want to retain to another table, then truncate and reload the original table:

```
-- select the rows we want to keep into a new table
create table tmptable as 
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    inner join table3 t3 on t3.b = t2.b
    where t2.a = t1.a
);

-- empty the original table
truncate table table1;  -- !! back it up first !!

-- reload it
insert into table1 select * from tmptable;

-- done
drop table tmptable;
```

Comment: That seems faster indeed. Is there any drawback to that ? Specific conditions in which it would be slower, or more broadly fail ?

Comment: @sroup: juste one. No other session should attempt to write the table while you are running this series of statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table1 t1 
WHERE exists (
  select 1 from table2 t2 
  where t1.a = t2.a 
    and exists ( select 1 from table3 t3 where t2.b = t3.b)
;
```

and make sure that `t1.a, t2.a, t2.b, t3.b` is indexed.

Also If you are going to delete most of the data on table, I suggest you to export those records which is not going to be deleted and truncate source table. After that you can import the exported records.

Comment: *export those records which is not going to be deleted and truncate source table. After that you can import the exported records.* May be not applicable - for example, if FKs or INSERT triggers exists. And one index by `t2(a,b)` seems to be more safe.

Comment: there is always compromise. It may be a good solution depending on the domain

Comment: The join is faster than this select exists. 25.57s vs 23.04s.

Comment: then you need to check your execution plan and indexes The sql profile which your RDBMS system uses may be different, more performans and so on. There is no single answer. You need to dig in

Comment: and for the other query? in order to compare them?

Comment: How much data exists in table t2 and t3

Comment: t2 has 10.000 rows and t3 has 5000 rows. t3 is a temp table with a single column that contains all the keys that will be deleted from t2 (b keys). But before deleting from t2, I need to delete all fk that point to t2 (a keys), so that's why I need to delete from t1. I have edited my question to add the execution plan for your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from t1
 where t1.a in (select distinct t2.a from t2 inner join t3 on t2.b = t3.b)
```

Comment: It doesn't change the speed much. The query took 25.75 sec vs 23.04 for my initial query.

Comment: wasn't able to test but looked like a valid alternative. thanks for the info.